# Search and remove from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

If I a value ID equals 1 and search an array I like to remove from the array itself where ID is 1 if found.

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )
)
```

new array

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
    )
)
```

I am using search_array, and I am assuming that because it is multidimensional it isn't finding it. Is there a way to search an array like above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just checking a single value, why not just use a foreach loop?

```
foreach ( $arr as $key => $value )
  {
    if ( $value['id'] == '1' )
      {
        unset( $arr[$key] );
      }
  }
```

Comment: If I changed the for to a foreach, bingo that worked. I tried this myself and was not doing the if statement correctly; which lead me to posting a question here. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

Another approach would be like (assumes you're filtering out ids of integer `1`):

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($val) { return $val['id'] !== 1; });
```

Note the above uses the cunningly named [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) function with an anonymous function as the callback (which does the filtering; you could use a 'normal' named function if preferred, or if you're not embracing PHP 5.3 yet).

Comment: How can I apply this approach to a three-dimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(/* your array */);
$remove = 1;

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
   if($val['id'] == $remove){
      unset($arr[$key]);
   }
}
```